# Wix- Invoke custom actions during rollback

Tags: wix, rollback

We have a custom action that has to be executed during roll back before file removal. How can we add a particular custom action to be executed as a first step  during rollback?

We have the below code but it is not working.

```
    <CustomAction Id="Delete_Directory_Rollback" BinaryKey="UnifiedAgentCustomActions.dll" DllEntry="DeleteDirectory" Execute="rollback" />
    <Custom Action="Delete_Directory_Rollback" Before="RemoveFiles" >NOT (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
```

## Custom Action

```
    string InstallPath = session["INSTALLDIR"];
    DeleteDir(InstallPath, session);
```

## Error message:

```
   Exception thrown by custom action:
   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.InstallerException: Cannot access session details from a non-immediate custom action
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.ValidateSessionAccess()
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session.get_Item(String property)
   at UnifiedAgentCustomActions.CustomActions.DeleteDirectory(Session session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
```

CustomAction Delete_Directory_Rollback returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking.

## Expected Result

```
    The same CA is working during uninstall but during roll back it is not working.
```

Comment: How is it not working? Please [edit] your question to give us error message, expected result, actual result, etc.

Comment: I have edited my post with all details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading/writing session property in that custom action.
If yes,then that may be your problem, as seen in log.